# How to find the count of multiple buttons on a webpage using Selenium Webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I have 4 Upload buttons on a webpage. Each of the upload button has the common functionality of uploading a file.

I am unable to get the count of these buttons using Selenium webdriver.
The id of the buttons are:

- buttonUpload_1
- buttonUpload_2
- buttonUpload_3
- buttonUpload_4.

The common entity for these buttons is the class name `buttonSecondary smallButton`

I have tried the below commands to get the count, but was unable to:

```
List<WebElement> buttoncount = driver.findElements(By.className(("buttonSecondary smallButton")));

List<WebElement> buttoncount = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//input[@class='buttonSecondary smallButton']"));
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get count using tagname as well

```
List<WebElement> buttons = driver.findElements(By.tagName("button"));
int buttonCount=0;
for(WebElement a : buttons){        
    if(a.getText().equals("buttonName")){
          buttonCount++;
}   
    System.out.println(buttonCount);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can solve it with `By.xpath` locator, `starts-with()` function and getting the `size()`:

```
List<WebElement> buttons = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//button[starts-with(@id, 'buttonUpload_')]"));
System.out.println(buttons.size());
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. However, i am getting the count as Zero and not the correct count.
Your suggestion does make sense, but unfortunately its not working.. 
any other suggestion for identifying an element by using part of its name ?

Comment: @BAshwin taking into account what you've provided in the question, it should work. Provide the HTML representation of the elements or a link to the web-site where we can see it. Also, are there any iframes on the page? Thanks.

Comment: here you go, below is the html representation :

<button id="buttonUpload_1" class="buttonSecondary smallButton" onclick="location.href='abc.com'" type="button

<button id="buttonUpload_2" class="buttonSecondary smallButton" onclick="location.href='abc.com'" type="button

<button id="buttonUpload_3" class="buttonSecondary smallButton" onclick="location.href='abc.com'" type="button

Comment: @BAshwin and here it is, these are `button` elements, not `input`, fixed.

Comment: ok. so is it not possible to count fixed button elements ? 
Thanks

Comment: @BAshwin it is possible. Have you tried the code from the updated answer? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If your all button will have same class OR xpath like you have taken in question then you can get total button count like :

```
 System.out.Println(buttoncount.size());
```

Size() will return you total num. of buttons.